# Merge users request

Tags: support, status-completed

How do I need to marge two users?

This is the "first" me:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6107/oscarryz

And this is the new me:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6899/oscar-reyes

I was supposed to login with the same open id, but what I did was:

1.- Login with a new open id
2.- Add the former open id ( I thought that would join the accounts )

Answer (score 1):

You can only ask a moderator to merge the accounts; a request on the meta site for the Q&A site where you have two accounts you need to merge is sufficient.